# callback post vars "disappearing"

Tags: codeigniter, curl, callback

man, I am stumped, and you probably won’t be able to help, but perhaps if I talk it through here:

This is a CodeIgniter custom CMS.

I am troubleshooting a custom cms someone else wrote; specifically, one of the payment gateways (HSBC - similar type library as PayPal or the like, but using Curl )

It has a callback function from the bank’s site, returning a set of $_POST variables.

PROBLEM: The $_POST variable are not accessible from app’s controller (I can see them returned by using httpFox)

I CAN:

1) return to a non-app .php page and print_r($_POST)  (i.e., callback url is just another page on my server, outside of CI)

2) post a Form from within or outside the app to the suspect controller, and print_r($_POST) with no trouble (i.e., this controller/app CAN receive a normal post)

So, trying to read the $_POST results from the callback itself is what is failing.

Any ideas on what to check, or how to track this? It’s obviously some setting somewhere, perhaps with Curl, but I’m at a loss. Happy to post code/more info once I figure out what direction to go in

TIA,

jeff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, a little closer observation final tracked it down:

the previous developer had the .htaccess to first add a trailing slash, then remove the .index.php?

it seems the callback was being routed to itself and as part of the process (along with some config settings, maybe) was losing the post vars. not sure if that's a precise description, but it was routing twice through the system

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Getting POST variables in CodeIgniter is acheived through the [input class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html).
The documentation states that all the superglobal variables are destroyed.

Getting the content of $_POST['something'] should then be done by:

```
$something = $this->input->post('something');
```

Comment: why do people keep telling me this?

"2) post a Form from within or outside the app to the suspect controller, and print_r($_POST) with no trouble (i.e., this controller/app CAN receive a normal post)"

$_POST works perfectly well in CodeIgniter; $this->input->post() is recommended, as it allows you to do cleaning. I am using $_POST here only for debugging

Comment: Are you using a custom parent controller?

Comment: it is, but I have also tried straight off the CI_Controller

my suspects are:
1) something with my CURL
2) dunno..since I can post directly to it from my own dummy form, just not read the callback data

Comment: Could you update your question with your callback url and the callback controller code?